# Is it possible to run caliper using IntelliJ 'run' command inside of main?

Tags: java, benchmarking, caliper, microbenchmark

I am new to caliper, and I want to know if it is possible for me to create a main method and then right-click and select 'run' using with IntelliJ?

```
public class Benchmark1 extends Benchmark{

    @Param({"10", "100", "1000", "10000"}) private int length;


    public void timeNanoTime(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            System.nanoTime();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliperMain.main(Benchmark1.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I try and run the above, I get this error:

```
Experiment selection: 
  Instruments:   [allocation, micro]
  User parameters:   {length=[10, 100, 1000, 10000]}
  Virtual machines:  [default]
  Selection type:    Full cartesian product

This selection yields 8 experiments.
Starting experiment 1 of 8: {instrument=allocation, method=NanoTime, vm=default, parameters={length=10}}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun.measure(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:394)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun.run(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:207)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain.exitlessMain(CaliperMain.java:131)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain.main(CaliperMain.java:78)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain.main(CaliperMain.java:66)
    at xxxxxxxxxxx(redacted).main(Benchmark1.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun.getRemainingTrialNanos(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:406)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun.access$400(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:95)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun$LineConsumer.call(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:513)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun$LineConsumer.call(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:495)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
The worker exited without producing data. It has likely crashed. Run with --verbose to see any worker output.

An unexpected exception has been thrown by the caliper runner.
Please see https://sites.google.com/site/caliperusers/issues

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also, since I am using IntelliJ, and my caliper is defined in maven like (i.e. test scope):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.caliper</groupId>
    <artifactId>caliper</artifactId>
    <version>${caliper-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**How would I run caliper from the command line?**

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a CLASSPATH confusion. You probably have an old Guava version on your CLASSPATH while Caliper requires 14.0 (where the method `elapsed(TimeUnit)` was added). Update and that's all.

In case you can't update, make sure that Caliper's Guava comes first... no idea what problems can occur, but I might work.

Comment: I changed to version 14, now I get this: `This selection yields 8 experiments.
Starting experiment 1 of 8: {instrument=allocation, method=NanoTime, vm=default, parameters={length=10}}
The worker exited without producing data. It has likely crashed. Run with --verbose to see any worker output.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51093', transport: 'socket'`

Comment: No idea... try `--verbose`, try to add some prints.

Comment: I can't add --verbose when I run it via right-click can I?  I'm not sure how to run it via commadn line yet.

Comment: Use `args` of `CaliperMain.main` as you wrote above. ;)

Comment: I got this `[trial-1] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IDEA
[trial-1] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IDEA
[trial-1]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[trial-1]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[trial-1]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[trial-1]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[trial-1]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[trial-1]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)`

Comment: No idea what it needs IDEA.class for; for me the same with Eclipse works. I guess you should post a [caliper issue](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/issues).